# Can there be an $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ closed under multiplication and addition with $|\mathbb{Q}| < |S| < |\mathbb{R}|$?

Tags: real-analysis, model-theory

In $ZFC+\lnot CH$, is the statement that there is an $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ closed under multiplication and addition with $|\mathbb{Q}| < |S| < |\mathbb{R}|$ true, false, or independent?

Comment: Can't you just take any set $S_0$ that is uncountable, but has smaller cardinality than the continuum, then take $S_1 = \Bbb{Q} \cup S_0$, which still satisfies the same property, and finally $S = \bigcup_n \{ \sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,1}\cdots a_{i,n} \colon a_{i,j} \in S_1\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Take $S$ which is a counterexample to the Continuum Hypothesis, and consider the field generated by $S$ given by Löwenheim–Skolem theorem. It has the same cardinality as $S$, say $\aleph_1$, and it is a field. So it is closed under addition and multiplication.